# Google Chart not taking up 100% of space

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Firstly, a big shout out to this example:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ca9151/google-charts-api-using-database-in-Asp-Net/ 
If you want a simple walk-through of building a Google Chart, then that is perfect.

In saying that ... both in that example, and on the one in my project ... I can't get the chart to start at the left of the designated section. it keeps indenting. It's worse when I hide the axis labels as the space just becomes larger due to the lack of words.

[image]

Does anyone know how to make them take up 100% of the width? (in the image, i want the chart to start at the red line and go all the way to the other side of the div)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by default, the chart will not fill the width and height of the container.

use `chartArea` options to stretch the chart to the edges of the container,
use `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` to leave room for the axis labels, title, etc.

```
chartArea: {
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
  top: 48,
  left: 48,
  right: 16,
  bottom: 48
},
height: '100%',
width: '100%',
```

redraw the chart on 'resize' to make it responsive,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Average'],
    ['2019/01', 1, 2, 7, 3],
    ['2019/02', 5, 1, 3, 3.5],
    ['2019/03', 4, 3, 9, 6],
    ['2019/04', 1, 3, 8, 5],
    ['2019/05', 2, 6, 8, 4],
    ['2019/06', 3, 1, 9, 3],
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 48,
      left: 48,
      right: 16,
      bottom: 48
    },
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',

    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: {title: 'Cups'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {3: {type: 'area'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  drawChart();
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly with the timeline chart too.