# Google Chart not 100% of div width - Contains Event Listeners to Redraw Chart from Proxy Table

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have implemented the suggestions per @WhiteHat in this post [Google Chart not taking up 100% of space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443537/7763687)

My `<div>` is 100% width however my chart still renders at only 400px wide.  See image.
[image]

I have the following chart options set.

```
        "chartType": "ComboChart",
        "containerId": "chartnull_G3G",   
        "view": {"columns":[2,3]}, 
        "options": {
           "chartArea": { "left": "auto", "right": "auto", "top": 50, "bottom": "auto", "width": "80%", "height": "60%", "backgroundColor": "white" },
           "width": "100%",
           "height": 500    
         }
```

My program flow contains the following steps.

```
//proxyTable_default and comboChart_default simply creates the content for the chart - this works without problem

var proxyTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(proxyTable_default(element_suffix));
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(comboChart_default(null, element_suffix, json.comboChart.options));

addListenersComboChart();

window.addEventListener('resize', function () { proxyTable.draw(); }, false);

proxyTable.setDataTable(proxyView)
proxyTable.draw();
```

Here's my listener and redraw functions which are referenced above.

```
function addListenersComboChart() {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function () {
        redrawComboChart(element_suffix, json.comboChart);
    });
}

function redrawComboChart(element_suffix, comboChart) {
    //Do many steps to calculate the finalView_forChart - this works without problem
    chart.setDataTable(finalView_forChart);
    chart.draw();
}
```

I cannot post my full codebase because it's 1000+ lines long.  Everything works ok until the chart does not draw 100% wide.  What am I missing?

As always, I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: hey @cmill! don't spot anything right off. any chance the chart's container is hidden when first drawn then shown later? also, I've never seen `auto` used for the `chartArea` dimensions, are you sure those work properly?

Comment: You are 100% correct!  I didn't include the unhide script in the original post.  I've rearranged it and posted the changes I made below.

Comment: The documentation for Combo Chart looks like the default chartArea.left (...right, top, & bottom) says it's auto.  That's why I have it set to auto.  
 https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#configuration-options

Answer (score 2):

@Whitehat is correct.  The div was hidden until after the `.draw()` was called. `lib_loadingStatus()` unhides the div

BEFORE

```
proxyTable.setDataTable(proxyView);
proxyTable.draw();    
lib_loadingStatus(element_suffix, "done"); //This code unhides the chart <div>
```

AFTER

```
proxyTable.setDataTable(proxyView);    
lib_loadingStatus(element_suffix, "done"); //This code unhides the chart <div>    
proxyTable.draw();
```

The chart now draws full size.  Thank you so much @WhiteHat (Saves the day again!)