# How to ensure the size of my chart is correct

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, charts, google-visualization

Edit: upon further testing, it looks like my chart is not even changing dynamically when the window size changes and I'm not sure why.

I am trying to create a dashboard, and so far, I have accomplished the below web page:

As you can see, the Hours/Category/Country chart is too small, however, the code to dynamically size it as the window changes size is correct. But, I would like it to be as big as the Amount/Category/Country chart. Where in my code can this be addressed?

Hours/Category/Country code:

```
<script>

  var chart, options, data;

  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General', 'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
      ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
      ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
      ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
    ]);

    options = {
      legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
      bars: 'vertical',
      isStacked: true,
      vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
      chartArea: {
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 80,
        width: '80%',
        height: '70%'
      }
    };

    const chartContainer = document.getElementById('hours-category-country');
    options.width = chartContainer.offsetWidth;
    options.height = chartContainer.offsetHeight;

    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chartContainer);

    chart.draw(data, options);

    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))

  }

  // On window resize, redraw the chart with new width and height.
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    const chartContainer = document.getElementById('hours-category-country');
    options.width = chartContainer.offsetWidth;
    options.height = chartContainer.offsetHeight;
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });

</script>
```

Amount/Category/Country code:

```
<script>

  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General', 'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
      ['2010', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
      ['2020', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
      ['2030', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
    ]);

    const options = {

      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
      bars: 'vertical',
      isStacked: true,
      vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
      chartArea: {
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 80,
        width: '80%',
        height: '70%'
      }
      
    };

    const chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('amount-category-country'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  
</script>
```

How my web page currently appears:
[image]

Comment: for starters, recommend making both `chartArea.height` and `chartArea.width` = `'100%'`. then use remaining `chartArea` options to provide room along the edges, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56443537/5090771). and when you have multiple charts that need to resize, first clear all the charts by using `chart.clearChart()`. after the charts are cleared, then redraw the charts. what happens, if the charts are not first cleared, their size can prevent the page elements from resizing properly. as such, re-drawing the chart has no effect.